# Wrong amount of results from Instagram API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I try the following request to get 8 latest post results from my Instagram account but, despite of I am using count=8 but, Instagram still provides only 5 results.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?count=8&access_token=<my-access-token>
```

But, when I use count=15 it provides 12 results! Where could be the problem? Any thought?

Thank you.